# ErrorDate parameters formatting ssrs to stored procedure?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have an issue with my parameters passed from SSRS to my stored procedure.

I have a date in US format with `MM-dd-yyyy` and in SSRS it is passed as `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Below my select from the stored procedure :

```
SELECT 
    tt.[sourceId] AS 'id',
    'Ticket',
    tt.[sourceId], 
    tt.[date_create], tt.[date_mod], tt.[date_close], tt.[date_solve],
    tt.[entityId],
    tt.[name],
    tt.[date], tt.[status],
    tt.[content_PlainText], 
    tt.[type],
    tt.[urgency],
    tt.[impact],
    tt.[priority],
    tt.[userId_lastUpdater],
    tt.[userId_recipient],
    tu.[sourceId],
    tu.[name], tu.[LastName], tu.[firstName],
    tu.[profileId], 
    tu.[entitieId],
    tc.[sourceId],
    tc.[completename],
    tc.[name],
    tc.[address],
    tc.[postcode],
    tc.[town],
    tc.[state],
    tc.[country],
    tc.[phonenumber],
    tc.[email],
    tc.[admin_email],
    tc.[admin_name],
    tst.[sourceId],
    tst.[statusText]
FROM 
    ticket_tickets tt
LEFT JOIN 
    ticket_users tu ON tt.userId_recipient = tu.sourceId
LEFT JOIN 
    ticket_company tc ON tu.entitieId = tc.sourceId
LEFT JOIN 
    ticket_status tst ON tt.status = tst.sourceId
WHERE
    tc.name = @flt_client 
    AND (tt.date BETWEEN @flt_StartDate AND @flt_EndDate)
```

Code parameters converting :

```
=CDate(Parameters!flt_StartDate.Value).ToString("MM-dd-yy")
```

Do you know to pass EU date formatting into US date formatting in SSRS parameters?

Comment: If both types are actually Date or DateTime then do not convert them to strings. The format of a date (`"MM-dd-yy"` or `"dd-MM-yy"` or `"yyyyMMdd"` etc) is just the output format, internally a date type column is just a date.

Comment: yep but then there is 0 result if nothing is change .... ?

Comment: Edit your question as state what data types each field/column/Variable/SSRS parameter is. If possible, show a sample of the raw data in your database including the ticket_tickets.date column

Comment: I found the solution by myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Cast the input StartDate and EndDate datetime to date in the stored procedure